# OpenSearch Complex Queries sorting and pagination

Tags: opensearch

I've been taking a look at the [Complex Queries](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/search-plugins/sql/sql/complex/) section of the OpenSearch documentation. Regarding the constraints of joining two indexes, I see the following two bullet points:

- You can’t use GROUP BY or ORDER BY for results.
- LIMIT with OFFSET (e.g. LIMIT 25 OFFSET 25) is not supported.

These are two very big constraints about the feature that are causing our team to avoid utilizing it for our app. We need to be able to paginate through the results (50 at a time). We definitely need to be able to sort the results by a given field. Are there any solutions you would suggest that would allow us to utilize this feature given our requirements?